# sqlite - finding if multiple records exist in table with single query

Tags: sqlite, pdo

I am trying to optimize an sqlite query (PHP-PDO) by having one query run instead of many queries on the same data. I have a table with a simple structure:

```
word
-----
aaaa
bb
cccc
dddd
ffff
```

now, I have a list of words `aaaa, gg, ffff`. For each of them, if the item exists in the table, I return 1 or else 0.

Is it possible to make this with a single query which with the aforementioned data, would return something like:

```
aaaa 1
gg 0
ffff 1
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `EXISTS`:

```
WITH cte(word) AS (VALUES ('aaaa'), ('gg'), ('ffff'))
SELECT c.word, 
       EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablename t WHERE t.word = c.word) exists_in_the_table
FROM cte c
```

or with a `LEFT` join:

```
WITH cte(word) AS (VALUES ('aaaa'), ('gg'), ('ffff'))
SELECT DISTINCT c.word, t.word IS NOT NULL exists_in_the_table
FROM cte c LEFT JOIN tablename t
ON t.word = c.word
```

If there are not duplicate words in the table you can remove `DISTINCT`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=6d233ddc09c966f447a588d85f6c8f4b).
Results:

```
> word | exists_in_the_table
> :--- | ------------------:
> aaaa |                   1
> gg   |                   0
> ffff |                   1
```